# Extend User Model to Use MongoDB

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I am trying to use Laravel and MongoDB together.  I have them talking unauthenticated, but now I want to add users, so I have this that i have used a few sourced and troubleshooting to bring together:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['email_verified_at'];
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
> {
>     "message": "Call to a member function prepare() on null",
>     "exception": "Error",
>     "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>     "line": 539,
>     "trace": [
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>             "line": 753,
>             "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>             "line": 720,
>             "function": "runQueryCallback",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>             "line": 534,
>             "function": "run",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
>             "line": 498,
>             "function": "statement",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php",
>             "line": 32,
>             "function": "insert",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
>             "line": 3339,
>             "function": "processInsertGetId",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Processors\\Processor",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
>             "line": 1869,
>             "function": "insertGetId",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
>             "line": 1330,
>             "function": "__call",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>
>  ..............Trimmed as I assume you dont need it all
>
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
>             "line": 175,
>             "function": "then",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
>             "line": 144,
>             "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/public/index.php",
>             "line": 51,
>             "function": "handle",
>             "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
>             "type": "->"
>         },
>         {
>             "file": "/mnt/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/resources/server.php",
>             "line": 16,
>             "function": "require_once"
>         }
>     ] }
```

Any thoughts please?  The weird part about it is that the user is getting created with I submit the post.

Comment: The errors seems like your MongoDB connect failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jenseggers and 9.2.1

I have had the same issue and my solution was to amend the User model
to use jenssegers not illuminate foundation

````
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;```

That said I just use breeze for the user authentication (DRY)
````